# Login another website from angular app with authentication done in code (bypass UI login)

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt

I have designed one app in angular 8 and wish to access another external website from my app.
When I redirect to website URL, it takes me to login page of that website (this is as expected). But i wish to skip going to login page and redirect to landing page (home page).

Explanation:
Consider two applications A (developed by me in Angular) and B (An external App or website).
I have login credentials for Application B. I have to integrate both applications. I wish to have 'Single Sign On' kind of functionality. I mean, once i am logged in from application A, i should be able to route to application B landing page (I should skip login page of application B). i wish to authenticate B from app A internally.
Is this possible to do?

Comment: You can try using Ifram and maybe passing your Token to the url inside it but i'm not sure if it's secure

Comment: ***I have username and password, as well as I can generate JWT from this.*** What does it mean? You generate a token for an external website? Or do you mean you request a token, using the credentials? Quite unclear question.

Comment: Apologies for not being able to make my point clear, I have added some more comments to help understand better.
Can you please reopen this question?

Comment: did you get any solutions for it?

Comment: No, not yet @vimalDev